# PyParsing large (million lines +) files

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyparsing

I wrote a parser for a DEF file (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Exchange_Format) by reading it line by line and using if-else statements. It works fine but I want a more clean and maintainable solution, so I found PyParsing (https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing).

I'm writing the grammar and testing the code but it takes minutes (I don't know how much because I never waited more than 5min). Using the if-else conditions in the parse that I wrote takes few seconds. Isn't PyParsing recommended for large files? The file I'm parsing has around 500k lines, but I will need to parse even larger ones.

Here's my PyParsing code so far. Please let me know if I'm doing something wrong:

```
import pyparsing as pp
pp.ParserElement.enablePackrat()

def parse_def(def_string):
    EOL             = pp.LineEnd().suppress()
    linebreak       = pp.Suppress(";" + pp.LineEnd())
    units_id        = pp.Literal('UNITS DISTANCE MICRONS')
    identifier      = pp.Word(pp.alphanums+'_!<>')
    number          = pp.Word(pp.nums + ".")
    dbuPerMicron    = pp.Group(units_id + number('UnitsPerMicron')).setResultsName('dbuPerMicron')
    parse_file      = pp.ZeroOrMore(dbuPerMicron)
    parse_file.setParseAction(handle_dbuPerMicron)

    return parse_file.searchString(def_string);

def handle_dbuPerMicron(token):
    dct = {}
    if token.dbuPerMicron:
        dct{"UnitsPerMicron": token.dbuPerMicron.UnitsPerMicron}
    return dct

ifile = open("large_file.def",'r')
to_parse = ifile.read()
ifile.close()

parsed_def = parse_def(to_parse)
```

So far I parsed only the number "dbuPerMicron" from the text bellow:

```
[UNITS DISTANCE MICRONS dbuPerMicron;]

Example:
UNITS DISTANCE MICRONS 2000 ;
```

But I will need to parse sections of the file that will repeat hundreds/thousands of times, depending the size of the circuit. Example the COMPONENTS section:

```
COMPONENTS numComps ;
        [– compName modelName
        [+ EEQMASTER macroName]
        [+ SOURCE {NETLIST | DIST | USER | TIMING}]
        [+ {FIXED pt orient | COVER pt orient | PLACED pt orient | UNPLACED} ]
        [+ HALO [SOFT] leftbottomrighttop]
        [+ ROUTEHALO haloDistminLayermaxLayer]
        [+ WEIGHT weight]
        [+ REGION regionName]
        [+ PROPERTY {propName propVal} ...]...;] ...
END COMPONENTS

Example:
COMPONENTS 65251 ;
- dm_rsci/U1 OR2X8 + PLACED ( 97240 138000 ) N
 ;
- core_inst/BUF_clk_G0_L3_22 BFX25 + FIXED ( 52904 42000 ) N + WEIGHT 1
 ;
- core_inst/BUF_clk_G0_L3_21 BFX25 + FIXED ( 42296 37200 ) N + WEIGHT 1
 ;
- core_inst/BUF_clk_G0_L3_20 BFX25 + FIXED ( 51136 15600 ) N + WEIGHT 1
 ;
- core_inst/BUF_clk_G0_L3_19 BFX25 + FIXED ( 52904 37200 ) N + WEIGHT 1
 ;
etc.
```

PS: by using the string checker parser (line split, if-else etc) it takes few seconds to parse the whole file and get all the information required, not just the dbuPerMicron at the beginning of the file.

Comment: Using `searchString` with a parser defined using `ZeroOrMore` will never finish.  Why not just do `dbuPerMicron.searchString`?

Comment: Hi Paul,  I was actually using parseString then I tried with searchString as I was having some issues before. Thank you for the tip, I will try it and let you know. One question: is PyParsing suitable for files with millions of lines? By suitable I mean that it is capable to parse such files in a few seconds, a minute max.

Comment: So, I tried with dbuPerMicron.searchString(to_parse) and now it's taking around 1min to process a 15MB file. Is this the expected performance?

Comment: Very likely - pyparsing is more for speedy development and easy maintenance than speedy data extraction. Packrat may not by buying you much either, since you have no recursion in your grammar - try removing this and see if things pick up.

Comment: 1min without Packrat, took forever with it so I disabled. Thank you for the info, I will split the file and do it in parallel then.